# PGFPlots: How to use a parameter t when plotting in 2D

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to plot some characteristic curves of the wave equation with parameter `t` which is time.

```
x - \frac{\omega}{k}t = c
```

where `\frac{\omega}{k}` is the phase velocity and `c` is constant.

In my example, I let `c = 2`; however, what do I with `t`?

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  [
  restrict x to domain = 0:5,
  restrict y to domain = 0:5,
  samples = 1000,
  ]
  \foreach \v in {1, 2, ..., 5}{
    \addplot[red, domain = 0:5] {x - \v * t - 2};
  }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't you rather want to plot x(t) against t or do I understand the phrase "characteristic curve of a wave equation" completely wrong?

Comment: @Philipp I figure it out or at least I found something that worked.  I don't even need to consider `t`.  `{x - \v - 2}` will produce the correct plot.

Comment: To be clear: `foreach` v= 1,2,..5 and given `c=2` and at discrete points of time(`t`, x-axis) you plot corresponding `x` values on y-axis right ? I suppose your `\frac{\omega}{k}=v` right ? How are the plots parametrized `t` and `v` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for simplicity, I made `c = 0` and `\frac{\omega}{k}=v` as texenthusiast noted.

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}%                                                          
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.8}%                                                         

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    restrict y to domain = -10:10,
    restrict x to domain = -10:10,
    samples = 1000,
    minor tick num = 1,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 5,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 4,
    axis x line = middle,
    axis y line = middle
    ]
    \foreach \v in {0, .5, ..., 5}{
      \addplot[red] {x - \v};
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

By ignoring the parameter `t`, the plot turned out correctly.  I am not sure why that is case but it worked.

> So if there is a way to do this without ignoring `t`, I would like to know as well.

[image]